# Cant figure out how to center the social icon html I was given

Tags: html, wordpress, center, centering

I used a website called niftybuttons to generate an html code for social icons for my website. Can anybody tell me how I can center the icons and possibly add space between them?

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/makemoneywithjus" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/retro/32/facebook.png" align="left" border="0" style="margin:1px;"></a><a href="http://twitter.com/makemoneywitjus" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/retro/32/twitter.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;"  align="left">
</a>

<a href="http://youtube.com/user/makemoneywithjus" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/retro/32/youtube.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;"  align="left">
</a>

<a href="www.linkedin.com/pub/justina-cipriano/92/779/6b5/" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/retro/32/linkedin.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;"  align="left">
 </a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/106075638630703080775/106075638630703080775/posts/p/pub" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/retro/32/google-plus.png" border="0" style="margin:1px;" align="left">
</a>
```

Comment: Put them inside a DIV that has margin:auto and a stablished width, and enclose each anchor inside a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

To add space between the Icons use padding

```
#list-left #set li a{
padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
ul#set li:nth-child(2) {
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px 2px 10px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8FLRD/)

```
div{
    position: relative;
left: 35%;

}
div a{
    margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
```